# When to call package-refresh-contents in init.el

Tags: init-file, package

I have found the following lisp code in an `init.el` file. I am wondering if this code logic is correct. I am learning Elisp and have reviewed the documentation and searched Stack Overflow. If this is too basic a question to ask, please direct me to a source:

```
(when (not package-archive-contents)
  (package-refresh-contents))
```

My understanding is that logic says that *if there is **no** package-archive file, then refresh the cache* .

Following are my questions:

1. Does Emacs download a cache for each of the sources in the package-archive list?
2. If `package-refresh-contents` is called only if the cache is absent, how do we (Emacs) keep the archive current? Do we have to manually use `M-x package-refresh-contents`?

Comment: Great question, I am currently running into a completely related issue. I have configured Emacs to automatically install packages by adding them to the `package-selected-packages` list and then calling the `package-install-selected-packages` function. Is there a way to make Emacs automatically run `(package-refresh-contents)` when it identifies that new packages ought to be installed? Currently, Emacs freezes when a package is not found in the cache simply because the cache is not updated.

Answer (score 1):

`package-archive-content` is used by `use-package` . it is the utility for installing packages. The snippet that you are quoting indeed refreshes the content or the `list-packages` in case it is empty.

It isn't a cache, it is only a list.

To update the list you need to manually call `M-x list-packages` and update it with `U`.

This update process might take a while therefore it shouldn't really be part of the init file for every time you fire up Emacs.

Comment: `<f1> v package-archive-contents RET`: "Cache of the contents of the Emacs Lisp Package Archive.[...]". To some extent, this is just a question of semantics of course, what exactly do you mean when you say "cache".

Comment: @npostavs I meant if Emacs will download a copy of the Emacs Lisp Archive. It looks from your response that is what it does.

Comment: Ah, I think the confusion here is that this variable is a cache of the package list (i.e., it is indeed "only a list" and also a cache).

Comment: I.e. it is the "contents" in the sense of a "table of contents" at the beginning of a book.  It's the list of what is available, rather than "the whole book".